# Laravel 5.4: concat data from related table in pluck

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

I am writing an assignment system for radio newscasts. The data tables:

```
station
id | calls
---| -----
 1 | cxri

newscast
id | name_input | for_station_id
---|------------|---------------
 1 | am         |  1

assignment
id | newscast_id | user_id
 1 |       1     |  5
```

The controller for Assignment.edit is as follows:

```
if (! Gate::allows('assignment_edit'))
    return abort(401);
    }
    $relations = [
        'anchors' => \App\User::get()->pluck('name', 'id')->prepend('Please select', ''),
        'casts' => \App\Newscast::get()->pluck('name_input', 'id')->prepend('Please select', ''),
    ];

    return view('assignment.create', $relations);
```

The Newscasts model:

```
public function for_station()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Station::class, 'for_station_id')->withTrashed();
}
```

Right now I get

```
"casts" => Collection {#451 ▼
    #items: array:2 [▼
      "" => "Please select"
      1 => "am"
    ]
}
```

I want

```
"casts" => Collection {#451 ▼
    #items: array:2 [▼
      "" => "Please select"
      1 => "cxri-am"
    ]
}
```

How do I make that happen?

Or should I denormalize the data and make name_input 'cxri-am' instead of 'am'?

**What I've tried:**
Accepted answer in [Laravel pluck fields from relations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40635146/laravel-pluck-fields-from-relations)

```
'casts' => \App\Newscast::with('station')->get()->pluck('name_input', 'id'),
```

errors with

```
Call to undefined relationship [station] on model [App\Newscast]
```

I included the Newscast model above based on the discussion in [Laravel: get/show data from related tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25523827/laravel-get-show-data-from-related-tables). Based on that discussion it appears to me the newscast should already be able to access the Station calls. But as shown above, the calls are not in $casts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close with what you have tried. The `with()` function needs the name of the relation function, not the table, so this should work for getting the relation model loaded:

```
'casts' => \App\Newscast::with('for_station')->get(),
```

As for getting the data to concat the way you want, I would make an [accessor](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators) on the `Newscast` model that will return the data you want:

```
function getNameInputStationAttribute() {
    return $this->for_station->calls . "-" . $this->input_name;
}
```

You would then use this like:

```
'casts' => \App\Newscast::with('for_station')->get()->pluck('name_input_station', 'id')->prepend('Please select', ''),
```

If I could point out a few other things, the return code of `401` indicates `Unauthenticated` whereas `403` indicates `Unauthorized` which would be more applicable to the `Gate` returning false. Also, class functions should be cammel case, so your `for_station` function should be `forStation` or even just `station`.

Comment: Thank you, @JRLambert ! This worked beautifully. I will also make some of the other changes you mentioned, and appreciate your pointers!